# Wh questions structure

Tags: american-english, british-english

What are the available options? Vs. what options are available?
Which one is the correct sentence?
Ans Please tell me what is the best structure for wh-questions?

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct and natural and mean the same thing. Neither is better.

There isn't a "best structure" for questions.